# How would I graph this function on Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, summation

[image]

I could graph 1/n^2, but I don't understand how to graph the fractional part (x).

Comment: Since this is a homework question you need to show what you have already done. How do you draw 1/n^2 ?

Answer (score 1):

The fractional part of x is

```
Mod[x,1]
```

You can also use

```
x-Floor[x]
```

Comment: ... or [`FractionalPart[x]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FractionalPart.html)